# Ruby Facebook API integration for OAuth and Game requests.

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sinatra

I'm building a cross platform multi-player game and want to be able to make player requests through Facebook.  The approach I would like to take is to have my own web service in the Ruby Sinatra framework which will act as a web service to my numerous game clients.

Is there a current ruby Facebook library/API that would work with Sinatra and allow me to do authorizations, requests, and post notifications to user's timelines?

Comment: did you tried `koala` gem?

Comment: when you find one, please post it back here.